# How can I import a static library in Python?

Tags: python, import, static-libraries

I have a static library (*liba.a*) and I want to use it in Python.

But `import` can only import dynamic library in Python.

How can I import a static library in Python?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't do this.  You have two options:

1. Recompile the library as a *shared library*. Then use [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to call methods from the dynamically-loaded shared library.
2. Build a [Python Extension](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) exposing a Python interface to the shared library.

Comment: Wouldn't the python extension also have to be compiled as a dynamic module?

Comment: Python extensions *are* dynamic modules.

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure, since the question is "how to import a *static* library in Python.