# Convert Static Lib to Dynamic

Tags: linux, libc

I have a `libsomething.a` file which is a static library with all dependencies included.

I need to be able to import this in Python as it is a Python C library. [According to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560594/how-to-import-static-library-in-python), it is not possible to use a static library as a CPython library.

How can I take my `.a` file and make it a `.so`, keeping all static dependencies baked in?

---

Background: I am using [Crowbar](https://github.com/ilianaw/rust-crowbar/) to build a CPython shared library which can be called from Python in AWS Lambda. Until now, it has worked flawlessly, but as soon as I added in dependencies which require OpenSSL, I get linker problems when running the code in Lambda.

The issue here is that the Amazon Linux image that is used to execute code has an ancient OpenSSL version. I have [recreated the runtime environment](https://github.com/naftulikay/docker-circleci-amazonlinux-rust/tree/lambda), but the issue is that the old version of OpenSSL no longer exists in Amazon's yum repository. This means that installing `openssl-devel` pulls down OpenSSL 1.0.2k, where in the runtime the version of OpenSSL provided is 1.0.1.

This results in linking failing at runtime in Lambda. Therefore, I need a way to build a (mostly) statically linked shared library. The only shared libraries I want my SO to link from are libc and the kernel, with everything else statically compiled in.

In the Lambda execution environment, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set to `/usr/lib64:/lib64:./lib`, so anything in the `lib` folder will be loaded, but only as a last result, and if I link against OpenSSL, I get the wrong version every time.

In Rust, I have the option of producing `liblambda.a` or `liblambda.so`, a static or a shared library. I'm assuming that producing a `*.a` and then converting into a shared library only linking to glibc and kernel dependencies.

Comment: How have you got that library? What is it doing?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do that conversion from static library to shared one (at least not in practice). Read [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) by Drepper.

One of the main reason is that shared libraries want (that it nearly need) to have [position independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (which static libraries usually don't have).

However, on Linux most libraries are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). So why don't you recompile your library from source code into a shared library?

<sup>(you might perhaps recompile that specific version of OpenSSL from source)</sup>

Comment: I have updated my question with more info about my build environment and the specific case in which things are going wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to [find a workaround within `rustc` and `cargo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263452/static-link-specific-library-to-shared-library).

Comment: PIC is not a language issue.