# How do I statically link the openssl-sys crate into a shared library?

Tags: openssl, rust, rust-cargo

I am using a library which depends on [openssl-sys](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl). According to the documentation, if I specify `OPENSSL_STATIC=1` as an environment variable, OpenSSL will be statically linked into the shared library output.

Due to [a host of complicated problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49262694/128967), I need to statically link OpenSSL into my shared library output.

Here is my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "api"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Naftuli Kay <me@naftuli.wtf>"]
publish = false

[lib]
name = "lambda"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
chrono = { version = "0.4", features = ["serde"] }
constant_time_eq = "0.1.3"
cpython = { version = "0.1", default-features = false }
crowbar = { version = "0.2", default-features = false }
libc = "0.2.29"
lazy_static = "1.0"
log = "0.4.1"
log4rs = "0.8.0"
openssl-sys = "0.9.27"
parking_lot ="0.5.4"
rand = "0.4.2"
rusoto_core = "0.32.0"
rusoto_kms = "0.32.0"
serde = "1.0.27"
serde-aux = "0.5.2"
serde_derive = "1.0.27"
serde_json = "1.0.9"
serde_qs = "0.3.0"
tokio = "0.1.3"
tokio-reactor = "0.1.0"

[features]
default = ["cpython/python3-sys"]
```

Here is my `lib.rs`:

```
#[link(name="openssl", kind="static")]
extern crate openssl_sys;
```

When I look at my `liblambda.so` produced, I still see it is linked against `libssl`:

```
[vagrant@api vagrant]$ OPENSSL_STATIC=1 cargo build
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.94 secs
[vagrant@api vagrant]$ ldd target/debug/liblambda.so | grep -i ssl
        libssl.so.10 => /lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007faa5f5bf000)
```

I seem to have told it in every way I know how to statically link `libssl` into the shared library output.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you done a clean build and rebuilt? Your output indicates that no compilation actually occurred, otherwise we'd see "Compiling" in the output. See also [OpenSSL crate fails compilation on Mac OS X 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34612395/155423), which includes the same advice.

Comment: @Shepmaster I have done a clean build.

Comment: It is not clear, where you get precompiled `libssl.a` and where you put it? Not sure that something like `openssl-dev` package contains staticaly linked openssl.

Comment: I am installing openssl-static which contains the static code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inspecting the `build.rs` file supplied with openssl-sys, I noticed two things.

1. If you do not set both `OPENSSL_LIB_DIR` and `OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR`, then it will try to detect the OpenSSL directories by calling pkg-config. If that succeeds (and it does in my system) then it will exit early, and never even considers the value of `OPENSSL_STATIC`.

   Arguably that's a bug, but I found that if I used this command line:

   ```
   OPENSSL_STATIC=1 OPENSSL_LIB_DIR=/usr/lib64 OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/openssl cargo build
   ```

   then it would perform static linking.
2. On my Centos 7 system, it was not enough to install `openssl-devel`. The static libraries are included in the `openssl-static` package.

Even after all this, it did not successfully build - there were a lot of undefined symbol references. Within the comments in `build.rs` it states that compilation options used when compiling OpenSSL may affect which API components are available - I assume this is the reason for the link failure. Apparently this is less of a problem from OpenSSL 1.1.0 (my system had 1.0.2).

My advice would be to compile OpenSSL 1.1.0 from source and link against that.

Comment: [THANK YOU SO MUCH](https://github.com/naftulikay/rust-openssl-static-example/pull/3)! I should have gone to source.

Comment: I raised [a bug](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/issues/878) on rust-openssl about this.